# Getting blank response while uplaoding large PDF file from Android app

Tags: java, android

I want to upload PDF file from android native application to server. I have checked the server configuration and everything is good like upload time and size. I am converting PDF file in base64 and trying to send to server. Server sending blank value of FILE[] (check the response below).

I have tried another method to upload PDF i.e multipart. This is also not working.

```
//Multipart code - 1st method

RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM).addFormDataPart("file", new File(pdfpath).getName(),RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/pdf"), new File(pdfpath).getName())).addFormDataPart("some-field", "some-value").build();
System.out.println("Multipart Data  "+requestBody.toString());

//---------------------------------------------------------
//Base64 code - 2nd method

public String converPDFBase64(File mfile) {
       ByteArrayOutputStream output=null;
       try {
           InputStream inputStream = null;
           inputStream = new FileInputStream(mfile.getAbsolutePath());
           byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
           int bytesRead;
           output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           Base64OutputStream output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
               output64.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
           }
           output64.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }        return output.toString();
   }

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//File send to server code

private Message getMessageObjectForMedia(String type,String media){
       HashMap<String, Object> input = new HashMap<>();
       input.put(RequestParameters.USERID, "" + SharedPreferencesMethod.getUserId(this));
       input.put(RequestParameters.TO_USERID, "" + user.getUserId());
       input.put(RequestParameters.MESSAGE_MEDIA, "" + media);
       input.put(RequestParameters.MESSAGE_MEDIA_TYPE, "" + type);
       input.put(RequestParameters.MESSAGE, "" +"PDF");
       String value = System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
       input.put("msg_identifer", value);
       System.out.println("Input Type   "+input);
       API.sendRequestToServerPOST_PARAM(this, API.SEND_MESSAGE, input); 

// service call for account verification

       Message messageObj = new Message();
       messageObj.setId(REMOVE);
       messageObj.setMsg_identifer(value);
       messageObj.setMessageMedia(String.valueOf(media));
       messageObj.setMessageMediaType(type);
       messageObj.setReadStatus("0");
       messageObj.setMessageAT("Sending...");
       messageObj.setUserId(SharedPreferencesMethod.getUserId(getApplicationContext()));
       return messageObj;
   }

//request send to server

{to_user=577, mediaType=pdf, media=okhttp3.MultipartBody$Builder@dfb1c38, message=PDF, userid=738, msg_identifer=1564994083868}

//response from server

{"success":"success","_POST{"to_user":"577","mediaType":"pdf","media":"okhttp3.MultipartBody$Builder@dfb1c38","message":"PDF","userid":"738","msg_identifer":"1564994083868"},"_FILES":[],"message_info":{"id":"4132","msg_identifer":"1564994083868","referenceId":"0","reply":"PDF","user_id":"738","reply_at":"2019-08-05 14:04:45","message_id":"115","ip_address":"00.00.000.000","read_status":"0","delStatusUserFrom":"0","delStatusUserTo":"0","media":"","mediaType":"","reference":{},"messagedAT":"Today at 2:04PM","message_date":"05-08-2019","message_time":"2:04 PM"},"RP_MESSAGE":"ALL_OKAY"}

//in response _FILES:[] is blank

//Expected Response
{
  "success": "success",
  "_POST": {
      "userid": "577",
      "to_user": "594",
      "message": "Hello",
      "mediaType": "pdf"
  },
  "_FILES": {
      "media": {
          "name": "Comics activity pack.pdf",
          "type": "application/pdf",
          "tmp_name": "/tmp/phpYR7O4q",
          "error": 0,
          "size": 2149146
      }
  }
}
```

I want to send large PDF file to server by using any method.

Comment: `It's showing the error` which one?

Comment: I have edit the question, please check the request and response.

Comment: ok, there is no error there. `//in response _FILES:[] is blank` you need to check this with your server - why it replies with empty `FILES`

Comment: also response from server is not a valid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I was using AQuery and now I have changed it. Now calling service by OkHttpClient and it's working fine.

```
public Message getMessageMedia(File file,String type) {
       Message messageObj = new Message();
       try {
           OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
           RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                   .addFormDataPart(RequestParameters.USERID, "" + SharedPreferencesMethod.getUserId(this))
                   .addFormDataPart(RequestParameters.TO_USERID, "" + user.getUserId())
                   .addFormDataPart(RequestParameters.MESSAGE_MEDIA,file.getName(),RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/pdf"),file))
                   .addFormDataPart(RequestParameters.MESSAGE_MEDIA_TYPE, "" + type)
                   .addFormDataPart(RequestParameters.MESSAGE,"" +"PDF")
                   .addFormDataPart("msg_identifer", System.currentTimeMillis() + "")
                   .build();
           Request request = new Request.Builder()
                   .url(API.SEND_MESSAGE)
                   .post(body)
                   .build();
           System.out.println("Input Data"+request.toString());
           client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
               @Override
               public void onFailure(final Call call, final IOException e) {
                   System.out.println("PDF Faliure   "+e.toString());
               }
               @Override
               public void onResponse(final Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                   if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                       System.out.println("PDF Response Error   "+response.toString());
                   }else{
                       System.out.println("PDF Response   "+response.toString());
                   }
               }
           });
           etMessage.setText("PDF");
           Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
           SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
           messageObj.setId(REMOVE);
           messageObj.setMsg_identifer(System.currentTimeMillis() + "");
           messageObj.setMessageMedia(String.valueOf(file));
           messageObj.setMessageMediaType(type);
           messageObj.setReadStatus("0");
           messageObj.setMessageAT("Sending...");
           messageObj.setUserId(SharedPreferencesMethod.getUserId(getApplicationContext()));
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           System.out.println("Media Message Error  "+ex);
       }
       return messageObj;
   }
```